# Are there official test vectors for historic ciphers?

Tags: encryption, vigenere, history, test-vectors

In many cases when cryptographic algorithms are published the paper also provides a set of test vectors that can be used by developers to verify their implementations.

For historic ciphers such as vigenere or ceasar there of course are no official papers. Is there any sort of "offical" test vector/KAT that is commonly used when testing implementations of historic ciphers?

Comment: RFC2410 includes a test vector for the "NULL encryption method"; does that count?

Comment: Did you check the Wikipedia? For example [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah but the examples presented there (ATTACKATDAWN) are often used for various things in the cryptography community - I don't think this counts as official test vector for this algorithm.

Comment: Shall we get out a time machine to make a telephone call to Julius Caesar's chief information security officer and ask what test vectors they use for interoperability from Hispania to Asia Minor?  Or, more to the point: What are the systems you're hoping to be compatible with?

Comment: "I don't think this counts as official test vector"; ok, what would make a test vector "official"?

Comment: "that is commonly used when testing implementations of historic ciphers" people don't commonly implement horribly broken historic ciphers (just horribly broken modern ciphers *cough* RC4 *cough*). At least not for production environments.

Comment: @Maeher I never mentioned implementations in production environments. One can still implement broken ciphers it for research/eductional purpouses and such. I am asking whats the best KAT to use for historical ciphers - hence don't come with a paper where the author provides a set of test vectors.

Comment: Many historic ciphers operate on specific alphabets rather than bits / bytes. So any test vector would first have to define an alphabet. I'm going to vote this as too broad as it is not about a specific cipher. If we name one official test vector for one specific cipher, then I don't see that answer as very useful.